# In the file's owner don't appears the Outlet

Tags: ios, exception, xib, iboutlet

I can not connect to the file's owner XIB. The application type is universal. In the file's owner in the "Referencing outlets" there is only "New Referencing Outlet" and under "Referencing Outlet collection" there is only "New Referencing Outlet Collection". There isn't possibility to connect the IBOutlet of UIImageView to the xib. In the file's owner don't appears the Outlet of UIImageView, despite I synthesize it. This is the code:

In RootViewController.h

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


 @interface RootViewController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>{

  }

 @property (nonatomic, copy) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
 @property (nonatomic, assign)BOOL fromRootViewController;


 - (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;



 @end
```

In RootViewController.m

```
  @interface RootViewController ()

  @end

  @implementation RootViewController

  @synthesize  imageView;
  @synthesize fromRootViewController;
```

In RootViewController_iPhone.xib and RootViewController_iPad.xib don'y appears the Outlet of UIImageView.

When I run the application this is a mistake:

NSInternalInconsistencyException. Could not load NIB in Bundle: NSBundle

How can I do? Thanks in advance

Comment: what class does represent the file owner? an `UIViewController` class or the `RootViewController` class? have you checked it in the _Interface Builder_ already?

Comment: In interface builder was written UIViewController class, now I fix it with RootViewController class and it works. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open IB and file's owner and look under custom class, check if the class name refers to the XIB is right or if it says a generic ***NSObject***, in this case, fix it.